# Interactive Choropleth using plotly & ipywidgets in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plotly, ipywidgets, choropleth

I am trying to create an interactive choropleth using Plotly and ipywidgets for the dataframe which the head looks like the one shown below.

[Data1.head()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfBgS.png)

The plot sums the values for all the available dates in the dataframe for each county.

[Output for available FIPS (aggregated values)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLEqL.png)

I want to filter the values for a particular date using a dropdown menu and plot the values corresponding to this date.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import ipywidgets as widgets
from plotly import *
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import plotly.graph_objects as go


date = widgets.Dropdown(
    options=['All'] + Data1.date.unique().tolist(),
    value='All',
    description='Date:',
)

# date = Data1['date'][1]  # If I use this instead of the widget defined above, the code works (at the cost of interactivity)

def func(date):

  values = Data1[Data1['date']== date]['Infected'].tolist()
  fips = Data1[Data1['date']== date]['Fips'].tolist()

   colorscale = [
       'rgb(193, 193, 193)',
       'rgb(239,239,239)',
       'rgb(195, 196, 222)',
       'rgb(144,148,194)',
       'rgb(101,104,168)',
       'rgb(65, 53, 132)'
   ]

  fig = ff.create_choropleth(
      fips=fips, values=values, scope=['IL'],
      binning_endpoints=[14348, 63983, 134827, 426762, 2081313], colorscale=colorscale,
      county_outline={'color': 'rgb(255,255,255)', 'width': 0.5}, round_legend_values=True,
      legend_title='Infected cases by County', title='Illinois State'
  )
  fig.layout.template = None
  fig.show()


interactive(func, date= date)
```

I am able to get the dropdown menu using this code, but it does not print the plot.

Alternatively, I tried to hardcode the date (commented in code) and it did return the plot for the specific date, at the loss of interactivity.

Can someone help me to get the plot where I can let the user choose a date from the dropdown menu and plot the choropleth correspondingly?

Comment: Please post the text version of your data and not pictures. The most likely think is that we can use the plotly dropdown without using `ipywidgets`.